# Android Socket connection refused

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip-address

I am trying to open a Socket on Android but everytime I try I keep getting connection refused error no matter what way I try.

The error happens on the following line of code where I try to create the connection.

---

```
Socket socket = new Socket(getLocalIpAddressString(), 8008);
```

---

The following is the method I use to get the local ip address:

---

```
public static String getLocalIpAddressString() {
 try {
     for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
         NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
         for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
             InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
             if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                 return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
             }
         }
     }
 } catch (SocketException ex) {
     Log.e("IPADDRESS", ex.toString());
 }
 return null;
```

}

---

And the error I get is:

---

```
WARN/System.err(3574): java.net.ConnectException: /192.168.2.163:8008 - Connection refused
WARN/System.err(3574):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
WARN/System.err(3574):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
WARN/System.err(3574):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:734)
WARN/System.err(3574):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:157)
WARN/System.err(3574):     at com.networks.phone.engine.SIPEngine.rtpTest(SIPEngine.java:1444)
```

---

I presume its an error with my Ipaddress and or port? But can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be the cause?

Comment: Can you telnet to the address and port number first to see what happens. It could be the actual computer you are connecting too.

Comment: I'm trying this on an actual Android device so I'm not sure that telnet would be much help?

Comment: This might be a dumb question but is there something listening on port 8008 on your device?

Comment: I get connection refused no matter what port I try :)

Comment: Right, well I guess I meant that if there isn't another program listening on port 8008 then you won't be able to connect.  Are you trying to accept incoming requests or connect to another program?

Comment: Hello i have the same problem you had, can you please tell me how you fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume you're trying to open a socket connection from an Android app to the same Android device.

Being based on Linux and all, maybe Android has some kind of firewall or connection rules that prevent your socket to connect successfully. Check the documentation, it may be an Android configuration problem and not a Java problem.

Comment: Maybe, connecting to another device might be a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

A properly coded android application which declares network permission in its manifest can accept connections on unpriveleged ports as there is no firewall on the device.

However, many wifi and most mobile networks will place the device behind NAT and an external firewall, so inbound connection attempts may never reach it.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the ipconfig command in prompt and then i used the "IPv4 Address" for connecting to current PC.

I have connected the Server successfully as well as sent & received bytes.

Android Client Side Code:

```
s = new Socket("192.168.42.85",12345);
```

PC Server Side Code:

```
socket = ss.accept();
InetAddress ia = socket.getInetAddress();
System.out.println("Client Address: " + ia.getHostAddress());
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to redirect the ports, have a look:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#redirections

Or maybe you can try forwarding the ports too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to use ServerSocket instead of Socket:

`ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocker(8888);`